# why better native module export doesn't work in my project?

Tags: typescript, react-native, node-modules

I'm trying to export my module following [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#better-native-module-export) guide but it didn't work and when i evoke the function initialize() it gives me this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of null ".

my CoinboxCollector.tsx in my node modules:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { CoinboxCollector } = NativeModules;
export default CoinboxCollector;
```

my index.ts in my node modules:

```
import CoinboxCollector from './CoinboxCollector';

export async function initialize() {
  return await CoinboxCollector.initialize();
}
export async function stop() {
  return await CoinboxCollector.stop();
}
export function addListener() {
  return CoinboxCollector.addListener();
}

export function removeListeners() {
  return CoinboxCollector.removeListeners();
}
```

my HomeScreen in the app :

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  NativeEventEmitter,
  NativeModules,
  Pressable,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
// const {CoinBoxCollector} = NativeModules;
import CoinboxCollector from '../node_modules/react-native-coinbox-collector/src/CoinboxCollector';
export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [off, setOff] = useState(true);

  const navigation = useNavigation();
  let coinInserted: number = 0;
  const coinValueStartExperience = 2;

  async function onCoinDetected(coin: any) {
    coinInserted = coinInserted + parseFloat(coin);
    if (coinInserted < coinValueStartExperience) return;
    //navigation.navigate('VideoScreen');
    console.log("hai pagato per l' esperienza");
    coinInserted = 0;
    console.log(coinInserted);
    await CoinboxCollector.stop();
  }

  const pressInit = async () => {
    // setOff(false);
    return await CoinboxCollector.initialize();
  };

  const pressStop = async () => {
    // setOff(false);
    console.log('getttoniera stoppata');
    return await CoinboxCollector.stop();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.CoinBoxCollector);
    const eventListener = eventEmitter.addListener(
      'onReceivedCoin',
      onCoinDetected,
    );
    // return eventListener.remove();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Pressable style={styles.btn} onPress={pressInit}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>Initialize</Text>
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable style={styles.btn} onPress={pressStop}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>Stop it</Text>
      </Pressable>
      {/* <Pressable
        style={styles.btn}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('VideoScreen')}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>navigate</Text>
      </Pressable> */}
      {/* {!off && (
        <View>
          <Text>Bravo hai Pagato !</Text>
        </View>
      )} */}
    </View>
  );
}
```

i tryed every type of import but it doesn't seem that nothing work.
thank you in advance for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the function getName of the module...it was mispelled

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).